# Writing to SQLite in iOS/iPad development

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite

I am having trouble writing to a SQLite database in an iPad development project. Here is my code to write to the database with an insert statement. Sqlite does not send back an error when I execute the statement but the data is still not saved in the database.

Simplified version of my insert statement:

```
//Insert Into POHeader(CustID, CatalogName) Values('0', 'webdemo')


@try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Orders.db"];
        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }

    sql = [self prepareSqlForPOHeader];
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;

    int sqlResult = (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL));

    if (sqlResult != SQLITE_OK)// (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{
        //success
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Comment: Not exactly my area but shouldn't there be something that actually executes the prepared statement?  (sqlite3_step?)

Comment: Just a though as I research this more. The database in the app is created by dropping an existing SQLite db in the resource folder. Could this be making it read-only then SQLite not returning this error for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add this line : `sqlite3_step(sqlStatement);`.

Change the code like:

```
if ((sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
else
{
    sqlite3_step(sqlStatement);
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what was missing. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @user731659: with pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the statement, that will work

Comment: Thank you both. It does seem to work to a point but still doesn't quite commit the insert all the way to the DB. If I execute the same exact query twice in a row it gives me a 'primary key' error which I see as a good sign because it shows the querys are executing. However if I run a select statement after the first insert, the data isnt in the database. Am I missing something here? Is it writing to some temporary DB that isnt committed into the actual DB?

Comment: dude your not even executing the insert.  Read up on Sqlite

Comment: I see it now. I didn't realize the sqlite3_step was what actually made the execution. Thank you for the help.

Comment: thats for a query - it may work for an insert/update statement as well but its not meant for that.  google inserting on Sqlite.